# CurrentDepth (32) is equal to or larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32

Tags: asp.net-core

when i call an API in asp.net core application it gives the error:
CurrentDepth (32) is equal to or larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32

in my startup.cs class in ConfigureServices i added the code below:

```
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
                                       Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
```

but remain still again

Comment: Core 2.2 or are you using a 3.0 Preview ?

Comment: it is 3.0 Preview

Comment: Well, no repro here. Post the full exception, state the exact VS and Framework versions etc.